# Web Part Deployment in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I've built a web part and after several deployments to a specific site, SharePoint suddenly won't give the option to deploy to a specifi site, a message is immediatelly displayed that the solution is deplyed globally.

I don't know what I did to cause this. I've been useing stsadmn -o addsolution method, except once when when I tried to just run the Setup.exe file.

Anyone has any idea why is it happenning and how to correct this.

Thanks,

EJM

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to retract the solution (with stsadm), if it doesn't work, use -force/-override, and then delete with the same.

Than try to do it again, and it should work.

Comment: I would retract the solution using the admin site, seemed to have worked up until now. I mean it retracs it, but any subsequent deployment of the same solution, goes directy global.

Comment: Try the force option with stsadm (its either force or override), when you redeploy the solution the server should refresh the state of the solution

Comment: When I run retractsolution with -name option, I get an error solution doesn't exist in the solution store. Also in the deploy solution page, the "Deploy to?" section has a message "The solution contains no Web application scoped resource, and therefore cannot be deployed to a particular Web application. It can only be deployed globally." So I guess that is the reason, but I don't know what a scope resource is and how it got changed along the way.

Comment: Have you tried using stsadm -o deletesolution -name ... -override?
The only problem should be is there are features for this solution that will be still activated when you redeploy it but nothing hazardous

Comment: also try running stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs, it will make the timer job run all pending erquests

Comment: Ended up recreating the whole web app and it took care of the problem. I'm still puzzled though and would have liked to learned from this. Thanks for our time, Mor Shemesh!